# how to configure cucumber and selenium with rails 2.3.11 to work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber

There are selenium features which work correctly on a rails 2.3.4 and they use firefox 3.5.19 for testing. However, after upgrade to rails 2.3.11, no selenium feature now works correctly, and they all time out when any feature tries to log in. The exact error is as follows:

==> Waiting for Selenium RC server on port 4444... Ready!

==> Waiting for rails application server on port 3001... Ready!

Mon Aug 08 16:49:10 +0500 2011 selenium-client received failure from selenium server:
requested:

```
cmd=waitForCondition
1=          var element;

      try {
        element = selenium.browserbot.findElement('webrat=login');
      } catch(e) {
        element = null;
      }
    element != null;
2=5000
sessionId=676e939365d84575bb1df9d69d5583ec
    received:
"Timed out after 5000ms"
called from /home/umar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
    And User logged in as 'newuser'                                                 #  features/step_definitions/selenium/users_steps.rb:1
  Timed out after 5000ms (Selenium::CommandError)
  /home/umar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
  /home/umar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p330/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
  ./vendor/plugins/webrat/lib/webrat/selenium/selenium_session.rb:46:in `fill_in'
  (eval):2:in `fill_in'
  ./features/step_definitions/selenium/users_steps.rb:3:in `/^User logged in as '(\w+)'$/'
  features/selenium/some_controller/some_feature.feature:8:in `And User logged in as 'newuser''
```

So it is a timeout related error that comes on trying to log in. How can i fix this?

The test selenium related files are as follows:

```
group :test do
   gem "rspec", "1.3.0"
   gem "rspec-rails", "1.3.2"
   gem "rspec-expectations", "2.2.0"
   gem "cucumber", "0.8.3"
   gem "cucumber-rails", "~> 0.3.2"
   gem "selenium-rails"
   gem "rcov"
   gem "webrat", "0.4.3"
   gem "autotest-rails"
   gem "ZenTest"
   gem "headless"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess - have you updated firefox too? Because selenium doesn't work properly with ff 5 and later and the output is exactly the same.

Comment: no, havent updated firefox, which version should i upgrade to? it was previously working with firefox 5.19

Comment: I'm using firefox 4.0, I mean what firefox is installed in your system. selenium-webdriver doesn't work with 5 and later because FF changed plugin compatibility checking routines.

Comment: was using ff 5.19 for selenium, will now install 4 and see if that works

Comment: firefox 4, example firefox-4.0rc1.tar.bz2 does not work. i tried installing it and using it, but it didnt. so apparently versions of firefox is not the problem, but i am not sure. is there any other version of firefox that you think would work?